# Inequality of variances

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, expectation, variance

I am trying to prove or disprove the following inequality.

Let $A,B,C$ be three random variables, such that
$$E[A^2] + E[B^2] = 1,$$
$$E[C^2] + E[B^2] = 1,$$
$$E[B(A+C)]= 0,$$
$$0 \leq A,C \text{ and } |B| \leq \sqrt{AC} \text{ almost surely}.$$

Is the following true?
$$2 \leq Var(A^2 + B^2) + Var(C^2+B^2) + 2Var(B(A+C)) + E[A]^2 + 2E[B]^2 + E[C]^2$$

Comment: Counterexample: $A=C=0$ almost surely, $B=\pm1$ symmetric.

Comment: Great example! I've added an extra condition to the inequality to disallow cases like this